# How to auto zoom page for mobile

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a [page](http://ndm.epizy.com/signin.php), I want to be it [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtEbM.png) in mobile.

But when I open it in mobile it is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3W18.png).

How to do that so that it is auto zoomed.

> **Note:** If the user tries to zoom out & zoom in it should not work.

Answer (score 13):

Use CSS media queries and set the wrapper in 

`(max-width: /*your desired viewport*/)`

and  control the width and font-size of your wrappper.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
If you don't want users to zoom in, use this meta viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: I always come to your answer just to get this line, I never seem to decorate it

Comment: I do that so many times here, it’s best to bookmark the run-to’s in a custom bookmark folder - saves much time

Answer (score 7):

The best thing to do is just copy: 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>` in `head` tag.

This will auto adjust according to the screen width & height.

`Media Query` **May / May not** be added, as per requirements.