# zoom fixed layout css

Tags: html, css

I have different webpages that have to fit the screen size perfectly. I can manually zoom in each webpage to the size where it just fits, but it should happen automatically. The content has to stay at the same ratio. So for example if the content fits the width, but not the height, than it doesn't have to be stretched out because the content needs to stay at the same ratio. So it looks a bit like the function "zoom" in CSS, but the zoom has to stop at the moment where the content still fits the screen.

I'll give a simple example of the html to test. But in my webpages, there are div's within other div's. Will the solution be the same as in this simple example?

```
<div class="Login">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fullname" style="width:15.580em"><br>
  Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't exactly get your question - what are you trying to achieve, and what have you tried that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: My question is a bit the same as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46275291/how-to-auto-zoom-page-for-mobile. At the moment, I have a lot of webpages, but they all have to be zoomed in automatically till it fits the screen size. The ratio of the content has to stay the same in all cases, so never stretch when it is for example full width, but not full height, for example: https://ibb.co/fbtuum. I'm a newbie to all of this, a week ago, I didn't know what CSS actually does.

Comment: If you want your page to automatically zoom on mobile, there is no need for a CSS manual zoom. Add this to your page's `<head>`-tag: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`. It will automatically zoom the page for you on mobile.

Comment: I read a lot about those viewports, but maybe I am doing something wrong, because nothing ever happens. Maybe because it's not on mobile, but an online tool? This is an image of how it looks with viewport, it stays small: https://ibb.co/iUpsEm

Comment: Yes, this is because you are not viewing it on a mobile device. Use the Chrome Dev Tools, they can simulate mobile behaviour. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/

Comment: Oh god, that explains a lot than. One problem, I cannot change the html code itself, so I have to use something like CSS. I'll see if that also works that way to see changes. I allready see that some buttons don't fit the screen and that I have to use the scrollbar, but I'm not stuck anymore now with the basic stuff, thanks for helping :)